# How to import library from cocoapods with the dot in the name?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

The library I try to link with is:

```
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'
```

but when I try to import this in `Bridging-Header` like this:

```
@import Socket.IO-Client-Swift;
```

I get following error:

> Expected `;` after module name
>   Module `Socket` not found

[image]

Any idea how can I do this to make it working?

Comment: I think it should be `@import SocketIO;` right?

Comment: What is the rule for this? Why it worked?

Comment: It is the mainfile of your cocoapod. You can see all other files are imported into this file. So you dont have to import manually. It is the main header file of pod

Comment: So everytime it depends on main header file's name, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, it should be `@import SocketIO` instead of `@import Socket.IO-Client-Swift;`

**But** how/why? The imported pod is `'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'` but not `'SocketIO'` so what is the logic behind that?

Well, actually the *Socket.IO-Client-Swift* is the name of the repository (pod) but NOT the `module` name.

Although there is a `SocketIOClient.swift` file in the [source directory](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/tree/master/Source) of the socket.io-client-swift (and it DOES contains `SocketIOClient` file/class that you should directly work with to create a socket), but you are not importing it directly; It's similar to the case of: when you want to use `Date` struct -for example-, you should import `Foundation`.

### *Side-bar note:*

Do you know that this is a legal (valid) code:

```
let date = Foundation.Date()
```

but because `Foundation` is implicitly imported, this is what we -usually- do:

```
let date = Date()
```

It is the same for all frameworks, for example the `UIKit`:

```
let view = UIKit.UIView()
```

:)

### *End side-bar.*

So, what are you importing (`SocketIO`) is the name of the module that contains the all needed files -including `SocketIOClient.swift`- to let it work as it should, it appears in its [Package.swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/blob/master/Package.swift) file:

> let package = Package(
>       name: "SocketIO" )

the name of the package is *SocketIO*.

---

**Another example:**

*Alamofire*: the name of the repository is Alamofire. Also, the name of the package is Alamofire! again you can see its [Package.swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Package.swift):

> let package = Package(
>       name: "Alamofire",
>       exclude: ["Tests"])

So, the name of the repository and its package name are identical, that's why you do `import Alamofire` and use it as `Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get")`.

Really hope it helped.